# sqlite ios thread access

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I'm trying to write a multithreaded (using NSOperationQueues for writes and executing reads on the main thread) application to access sqlite database data.  I understand that sqlite isn't threadsafe by default, but we've added the multithreaded preprocessor macro and set our journaling mode to wal.

According to this sqlite documentation: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6 it seems we need to finalize all of our prepared statements before writing anything.  Is this true?  Is there any way to avoid this?  What if we have two handles to the same database?

Basically we want to have multiple reads and a single write going on at one time but are trying to figure out the best way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So it's either finalize this thing and have so-so threading up, or don't finalize and risk a double or more thread access to a resource (a HUGE no-no)?

Comment: well our second thread (using the nsoperationqueue) would only access the writes...all the reads would be on the mainthread so they wouldn't share resources

Comment: well, I guess the only way to figure it out would be to try it yourselves.  iOS is UNIX-Like, so I wonder how far their advice goes anyhow... +1

Comment: it might work at first, but unfortunately it's hard to test multithreading to reproduce any bugs =(

Answer (score 2):

The threading mode is determined by compile time, startup or runtime options. More details here:

http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

The docs say serialized is the default which means you're fine to use from multiple threads - it will guard you with all access being serialized. If you want more parallelism, you can use multi-threaded mode with multiple connection objects.

If you use multi-threaded, ensure the same db connection object is not used by more than one thread at any one point in time:

> Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
>   threads provided that no single database connection is used
>   simultaneously in two or more threads.

But, make sure the complexity is justified.  As with all performance issues, measure before and after.

EDIT: one way to ensure this is to create your own pooling mechanism.  Create a pool of n connection handles that each parallel tasks gets and releases to the pool.  The docs say that multi-threaded mode is completely safe across connections.  That way, you don't have to worry about all other transactions or statements being finalized.  A separate read thread/connection and write thread/connection is effectively a very simple hardcoded pool.

Comment: so basically two handles...one for reads on the mainthread and one for writes on a background thread?

Comment: rather than relying on no transactions and all statements to be finalized, another approach would be a pooling approach.  Since mult-threaded mode is known to be safe with different connection handles, create a pool that contains n connection handles that the parallel tasks can use.

Comment: so you're saying two handles will solve my problem? one handle for reading and one handle for writing?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you have a pool of n connections in a pool.  a parallel task can take/lease a connection out of the pool, use it, return it to the pool.  That way, a connection is guarenteed to be used by only one thread at a time, you keep the connections low by pooling and sharing and you're safe.  But ...

Comment: But ... make sure you need that complexity.  Make sure you measure.  How does your app work?  Is there a main app thread reading with background writes?  If so, then the simplest pool is a single readers and writer and you get the most benefit.  Are your transactions short?  then, maybe multithreading and all this is overkill and the serialized default is sufficient ... hard to say without understanding the dataacess patterns and measuring.  Simpler is better ...

Comment: if so, then why does the application crash and get sqlite errors when we use one connection with multiple threads? yes, right now everything is on the main thread, but we want to change this...we're thinking of having all the reads on mainthread, and all the writes on a background thread but it's causing issues

Comment: Because you can't use one connection from multiple threads - a connection should only be used by a given thread at any given point in time but you want to keep the connections low.

Comment: so to my original question, one handle for reads and one handle for writes will be sufficient?

Comment: It will be safe only if the no two reads or no two writes happen at the same time.  In multi-threaded, make sure a given connection is used by one thread at any given point in time. (a pooling pattern guarentees that) If you can guarentee that and it's more optimal that serialized, then yes.

Comment: sqlite allows for multiple reads...in fact with WAL, it allows for multiple reads with 1 write... as i mentioned in the original post, we plan to have two handles - 1 for reads and 1 for writes where the writing handle has a max concurrency of 1

Comment: Yes, what you're describing is effectively a vey simple pool - a pool of two handles, one for read and one for write.  I was pointing out that *if needed* you could have more than one of each.  And instead of hardcoding the concept of one read and one write, it could be a generic pool of n.  Just two ways of looking at it.

Comment: to do this, do you know if we have to finalize our prepared statements?